# How do I get a variables value to be constantly decreased when operated on (+/- the requested change) (in javascript:alert boxes))

Tags: javascript, html, variables, alert

```
<script>
var x = 40
function ale() {

    a = document.getElementById("find").value
    if (a == 'Spark' || a == 'Fire') {
        var monster = x
        var damage = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
        alert('Enemy has ' + (monster - damage) + ' Health!');
    }


    else if 

    (a == 'water' || a == 'bubble') {
        var monster = x
        var damagew = 10
        alert('Enemy has ' + (monster - damagew) + ' Health!')
    }
```

Hi so what happens is whenever I type for example water the health of what x was 40 is now 30 but now I click it again and it tells me its the same thing 30 when I want to be 20 and then if I type fire for it to give me 20 - Math.floor(Math.Random()*10) to give something like 17 pretty much how my text based game works. But as for now it just keeps giving me 30 everytime I write water. Is it possible to get the x value working where it can constantly be edited then maintain its value after its been edited by for example a subtraction?

Comment: Did you forget the semicolons? For example var monster = x; var damage ...

Comment: @maťo Semicolons are optional in JS.

Comment: you have to decrease x by 10 if you want 20 next time on click.X=X-damagew after alert.

Comment: If you want `x` to change, you need to assign to it.

Comment: @PanktiJain Thanks alot works well guess I just needed to remember how some high school math worked

Comment: No problem. i have posted as answer so if somebody is looking for answer then it will help them also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to decrease x by 10 if you want 20 next time on click.X=X-damagew after alert.

Answer (score 0):

What you would need to do is this:

```
(a == 'Spark' || a == 'Fire') {
    var monster = x
    var damage = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
    alert('Enemy has ' + (monster - damage) + ' Health!');
    HEALTHVARIABLE -= damage;
}
```

HEALTHVARIABLE is just to be used in place of whatever you are currently using as the variable to store your monsters' health.

I can't help but point out that you are missing a curly bracket in your code. I'm not sure whether you just didn't copy the last line of your code that contains said bracket, or you have another bracket somewhere else out of place in your code that makes up for it and forces it to still work, but if you are still having an issue with your code that is something you should look at. Best of luck.